# What does "dotnet mydll.dll %*" do?

Tags: .net-core, cmd

I'm trying to deploy my .NET 6 application to a App Service and have it start automatically. I've not found any documentation for this purpose, but I've found various blog and comments that suggest that a 'run.cmd' command file in the root directory will be executed when a Azure App Service starts. Further, they suggest the content of the file should be:

```
"dotnet WebApi.dll %*"
```

I understand the "dotnet WebApi.dll" part, but I can't figure out what the "%*" is doing. Anyone have a clue or a link to share?

Comment: in batch scripts, `%*` means "all parameters" (described in `call /?`)

Comment: If you execute `run.cmd alpha beta gamma`, `%*` = `alpha beta gamma`, `%1` = `alpha`, `%2` = `beta`, etc.